# If definition of elements in table

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, debugging, broken-code

I need to define a table where the definition of the elements differs if the indices $i$ and $j$ are equal or different. In particular I have to implement the following formula $$(K_1^{(1)}(m_1,m_2))_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{M_{ij}^{(1)}}{a_i-a_j}\left[\left(\frac{\alpha_s(m_2)}{\alpha_s(m_1)}\right)^{a_j}-\left(\frac{\alpha_s(m_2)}{\alpha_s(m_1)}\right)^{a_i}\right]&i\neq j\\
M_{ii}^{(1)}\left(\frac{\alpha_s(m_2)}{\alpha_s(m_1)}\right)^{a_i}\log\frac{\alpha_s(m_1)}{\alpha_s(m_2)} &i=j
\end{cases}$$

All the relevant matrices have been defined as table and I need to define $K_1^{(1)}$. What I have done is as follows

```
K1 = Table[If[i == j, M15[[i, i]] (αsΛ/αsμ)^a5[[i]] Log[αsμ/αsΛ], M15[[i, j]]/(a5[[i]] - a5[[j]]) ((αsΛ/αsμ)^a5[[j]] - (αsΛ/αsμ)^a5[[i]])], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}] // Chop
```

And what I get is various error of the form "Power: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered." and "Infinity: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered." which I imagine they would come from the program trying to evaluate the first expression even when $i=j$.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add info. such as`Dimensions[M15]` and `Length[a5]`? Or even these items, if possible.

Comment: @Syed Yes, dimensions[M15] outputs $\{10,10\}$ while length[a5] output $10$

Comment: Can you ensure the ai does not equal aj?

Comment: Have you executed a `MatrixForm` command on `M15` and `a5` in your notebook prior to using these in the computation? It would be helpful to include these items in your post.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWXAy.png is the output of your command on my machine.

Comment: @jmm Looks like you are right! There are some entries in a5 which are the same! I'll look into it and get back. I'm going to give the full code later.